# How to add two data sets on one bar graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you put two data sets on the same bar graph?  I tried this code.  This should be simple enough to help anyone with the same problem?

```
x = groups1_table.plot.bar(color='blue')
x = groups2_table.plot.bar(color='red')

plt.show()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, please post a MRE (min reproducible example) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Okay, think the vague variables and question should meet the MRE guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ax` in matplotlib.
Since you have not posted MRE, I am assuming the data points.
You can proceed with something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1=[1,2,3,4,5]
y1=[6,7,8,9,15]

x2=[16,17,18,16,19]
y2=[20,22,23,26,21]

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax=plt.bar(x1,y1,label='x_list')
ax=plt.bar(x2,y2,label='y_list')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Again you have to change the code to meet your preferences. Just know that you can place as many graphs as you want on a same plot. Just use the same axes object `ax` to plot them.

OUTPUT:
[image]